# Topological properties of the chord space $C^2(X)$ and it’s generalizations

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The chord space of $X$ is defined as the set
$$C^2(X)=\frac{X\times X}{(x_1,x_2)\sim (x_2,x_1)}$$
In general, $C^n(X)$ is the set of unordered $n$-tuples with points in $X$:
$$C^n(X)=\frac{X^n}{x\sim\sigma x,\ \sigma\in S_n}$$
I’ve been able to calculate that $C^2(S^1)$ is the Möbius strip. I feel that $C^2(S^n)$ is some quotient on the boundary of either $G_1(\text{T}S^n)\times I$ (seen by parameterizing by location of the midpoint and then the direction of the chord), or the disk bundle bounded by the unit tangent bundle $\text{UT}\mathbb{R}\text{P}^n$ (seen by paramaterizing by the direction of the chord and then the location of the midpoint). Aside from $C^2(S^1)$, I have not been able to calculate $C^m(S^n)$ for $m\geq 2$, $n\geq 1$.

My question is what is $C^m(X)$ and $H_k(C^m(X))$ when $X=S^n$? Also if
possible, what about when $X$ is a product or wedge of spheres?

Comment: This is equivalent to the concept "[symmetric product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_(topology))". A particular example: when $X=S^2$, we have $C^n(S^2)\approx \Bbb CP^n$.